# How to control page number on multipage TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I am working on page numbering on toc and  need page number should start from TOC. In example given below, there are two pages for TOC followed by 2-blank pages.  But i observe, page number on toc is 3. How can i make it to 1?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{146,243,224}

\newcommand{\addstufftotoc}[2][toc]{% \addimagetotoc[<toc>]{<stuff>}
\addtocontents{#1}{#2}}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}% <cmd>
{\begingroup}% <search>
{\begingroup\normalfont\Large\bfseries}% <replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>
\newcommand\mdframedintoc{\par\bigskip%  
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=myblue]
Some contents for the \texttt{mdframed} environment.
\end{mdframed}\par\bigskip
\begin{mdframed}% mdframed for the image
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-a}
\end{mdframed}%
}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}{\@starttoc{toc} \mdframedintoc}  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\mbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage


\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{First section}
\addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2    \baselineskip]{example-image-a}\par}
 \section{Second section}
  \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2 \baselineskip]{example-image-b}\par}
 \section{Third section}
 \section*{Fourth section}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Fourth section}
 \section{Last section}
 \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2 \baselineskip]{example-image-c}\par}
 \section{First section}
 \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2   \baselineskip]{example-image-a}\par}
 \section{Second section}
 \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2    \baselineskip]{example-image-b}\par}
 \section{Third section}
 \section*{Fourth section}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Fourth section}
 \section{Last section}
 \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2   \baselineskip]{example-image-c}\par}
 \section{First section}
  \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2  \baselineskip]{example-image-a}\par}
 \section{Second section}
 \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2 \baselineskip]{example-image-b}\par}
 \section{Third section}
 \section*{Fourth section}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Fourth section}
 \section{Last section}
 \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2  \baselineskip]{example-image-c}\par}
 \section{First section}
 \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2 \baselineskip]{example-image-a}\par}
 \section{Second section}
 \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2  \baselineskip]  {example-image-b}\par}
 \section{Third section}
 \section*{Fourth section}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Fourth section}
 \section{Last section}
 \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2 \baselineskip]{example-image-c}\par}
  \section{First section}
 \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2   \baselineskip]{example-image-a}\par}
 \section{Second section}
 \addstufftotoc{\nobreak\smallskip\protect\includegraphics[height=2   \baselineskip]{example-image-b}\par}
 \section{Third section}
 \section*{Fourth section}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 explicit

```
\mbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
```

entries before `\tableofcontents`. This is what is inserting the two empty pages. If you wish to keep those yet start from page one, insert `\pagenumbering{arabic}` immediately after the second entry. Otherwise, remove the first two duplicate entries, and your ToC will start from page 1 naturally.

The reason why this works is because `\pagenumbering` resets the page counter to one (via `\global\c@page \@ne`):

```
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \global\c@page \@ne \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname
   \c@page}}
```

Of course, issuing `\setcounter{page}{1}` would be similar.